# Help with section title style

Tags: titlesec

I'm trying to do a document where the section title be the most simple but I can't, even I saw documentation... but I'm not too familiarized with the environment.My code is:

```
    \documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[top=2.5cm, left=3.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{titlesec} 
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{1em} 
    \setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

    \titleformat{\section }
    {\normalfont \bf \upshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}

    \begin{document}
    \section{Section}
    \lipsum[1-30]
    \end{document}
```

and the only that I want is to center the title section (including the number) with bold style and a little bigger than the normal font I'm using. Something like:

```
    \begin{document}
    {\centering \textbf{1. Section}}
    \end{document}
```

If someone could help me or advice me I would be very grateful. Because I can't advance on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are. For centred titles, with the label on the same line, you should select the `[block]` shape, and use the `\filcenter` command.

Just a few remarks: usually, one does not use both `\parskip` and  paragraph indentation. These parameters aim at making clear to the reader where a new paragraph starts. One tool is enough, if you do not want to be redundant. A sensible value for `\parindent` is `1em`, as it will automatically be wider if you choose a larger font size. Last, `\bf` has been  deprecated for nearly 25 years, you should code `\bfseries`.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[,left=3.5cm, right=2.5cm, vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}

\titleformat{\section }[block]
{\bfseries\Large\filcenter}{\thesection.}{0.5em}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\lipsum[1-30]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the remarks Bernard! With respect to the font size of the title, Isn't a way to choose this size exactly? like 12.5pt for example.

Comment: Yes, there's a way for local usage:  add `\fontsize{12.5pt}{15pt}\selectfont`. Preferably do not use the default font, but, say `\lmodern` For the default, you'd have to load `extsizes`. Beware it should be a used locally, as you may have inconsistent math font sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Without any package:

> [image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection
{section}%                   % name
{1}%                         % level
{0mm}%                       % indent
{-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}% skip before
{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}% skip after
{\centering\large\bfseries}} % the style
\makeatother 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\begin{document}
\section{Simple title}
The only that I want is something like: \verb|{\centering \textbf{1. Section}}|
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is any advantage doing this without a package?

Comment: @hllspwn This do not change a lot of default macros (only one) and it  does not add anything new. Maybe load a bit faster but overall could prevent some potential conflicts with some package or  class (search for "titlesec conflicts" to some examples). But  I am not against use `titlesec`, it is mostly a matter of preferences and the needs of your project.